# How to get Month in all upper case

Tags: linux, date, case

I have two digit month value (01 to 12).  I need to get the three letter month abbreviation (like JAN, FEB, MAR etc.) I am able to get it in mixed case using the following command:

```
date -d "20170711" | date +"%b"
```

The output is "Jul"  I want it to be "JUL".  Is there a standard date option to get it?

Comment: FYI that command probably doesn't do what you think it does (HINT: try `date -d "20170611" | date +"%b"`)

Comment: @steeldriver, on mobile, can't try, what does?

Comment: @user1717828 AFAIK the output of the first `date` command is simply discarded; the second `date` command prints the *current* month regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a fairly static piece of information (barring more [intercalary events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)), just use built-in shell commands:

```
function capdate() {
  case "$1" in
  (01) printf "JAN";;
  (02) printf "FEB";;
  (03) printf "MAR";;
  (04) printf "APR";;
  (05) printf "MAY";;
  (06) printf "JUN";;
  (07) printf "JUL";;
  (08) printf "AUG";;
  (09) printf "SEP";;
  (10) printf "OCT";;
  (11) printf "NOV";;
  (12) printf "DEC";;
  (*)  printf "invalid"; return 1;;
  esac
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ m=$(capdate 01); echo $?, $m
0, JAN
$ m=$(capdate Caesar); echo $?, $m
1, invalid
```

Adjust the text if your locale has different `date +%b` names.

Comment: +1 if you use an array's indices instead of a `case` statement :p

Answer (score 23):

```
^      use upper case if possible
```

Result:

```
$ date +%^b
JUL
```

Bonus: how I got this answer:

<kbd>man date</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>/case</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: Excellent point with using `^`! This answer just needs to take into account the variable input of the month number.

Answer (score 5):

You could just pipe it to [`tr(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
date -d "20170711" +"%b" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Comment: for some reason I could not make tr work.    But following worked :

Answer (score 1):

`date -d '20170711' '+%^b'` and `date -d '20170711' '+%b' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` works well.

You can also do this using parameter expansion:

```
$ month=$(date -d '20170711' '+%b')
$ echo "${month^^}"
JUL
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using awk

```
date -d "20170711" | date +"%b" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
```

Comment: why not just tell `date` to format it in the same command? `date -d 20170711 +%b` ?

Comment: it's already in 'tr' solution, no need to repeat I thought. Also since author was already on the right track, added what was missing to his command